# Finding the Mean and Covariance matrix from a joint p.d.f.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $\overrightarrow{X}=(X_1,X_2)$ has p.d.f $f(\overrightarrow{x})=C \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-4x_1x_2+5x_2^2-2x_1+6x_2))$.

How do I find the mean and covariance matrix of $\overrightarrow{X}$?

I thought this was a bivariate normal distribution, but turns out it's not. I also tried finding the marginal distributions, but it's too ugly. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: $-\infty<x_1,x_2<\infty$?

Comment: The question did not mention it, but yes, I suppose so.